# ASP.NET UserControl with validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I need to create my UserControl with validation.
I created UserControl:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyValidationControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Labs.MyValidationControl" %>


 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Name">Name</asp:Label>     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field ''Name'' is required." ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br/>

    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Password">Password</asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RangeValidator runat="server"  MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="10" Type="Integer" id="rngText" controltovalidate="TextBox2" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" errormessage="The value must be from 1 to 10!" />
    <br />
```

Then I use UserControl on the form:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <asp:MyValidationControl runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

When I start my application I see nothing on this page.

Comment: What happens when you try to submit invalid values?

Comment: how you are firing this Validations?if it is a button Have you set the correct validation group to the button?

Comment: The problem is not in validation. There is nothing at the form at all

Comment: Have you added the user control reference in the page?

Comment: Can you show that Usercontrol registry code ?

Comment: I dont understand what is registry code. This?                  public partial class MyValidationControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
 {
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
 }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23139/discussion-between-stalli-and-kiran1016)

Comment: Can you show the whole page code?

Comment: This is the whole page code. Also I tried without masterpage - the same result

Comment: <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="Labs" Assembly="Labs" %> where  you are referring user control ,you have src attribute in which you should give your  usercontrol path

Comment: "Src control can not be bound to tag prefix. Specify tag name or replace it with namespace"

Comment: I think attributes Namespace and Assembly give the path.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. 
First, thanks to Kiran1016. He gives me article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx

Second, UserControl must not be in the root directory of the project. I put it in the directory "Controls".